# curl on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, curl

can curl be used on google app engine ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  To make HTTP requests, you need to use the urlfetch service.

urllib, urllib2, and httplib on App Engine are patched to transparently use this API for you, so any third-party module that does HTTP requests using one of these standard modules will work.

The 'c' in cURL is there because the library is written in C; cURL interfaces in other languages (like pycurl) use the libcurl library, and can't be use on App Engine, as modules that reply on C extensions are not allowed.

Comment: is there any way then by which i can simulate twitter and facebook logins?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommand using the URL fetch service.
For example in python

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers to this are a bit dated. cURL totally works on GAE now. We are using it a number of places in our PHP application that is hosted on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Twitter4J http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html - specifically mentions App Engine support.

Answer (score 1):

It's a real old question and I end up here, so someone else might as well.

App Egine supports cURL requests.

Follow the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/issue-requests