# pycurl with Google app engine

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine, pycurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [curl on app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571627/curl-on-app-engine)

Does GAE support pycurl ?

I have downloaded the pycurl setup (pycurl-ssl-7.18.2.win32-py2.5.exe) from this link :http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/ . And setup was installed in **C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\curl**

Now how can in integrate pycurl with  Google app engine project ?

Comment: @Nijin Narayanan  no google appengine don't allow you install third package by yourself

Comment: @timger You can use third-party packages, just not ones that use C modules.

Comment: @timger That is not correct. You can install 3rd party python modules, as long as they are pure python. Any packages that have compiled C libraries will not work.

Comment: @Nick So i can use pucurl with Gae is it ? how can i use pycurl in gae project?

Comment: @Nijn No, you can't, since as others have pointed out, it uses a C module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/:

> PycURL is a Python interface to libcurl [...]

You can't use PycURL on GAE since it requires this C library.

As the commenters said, use the native [URL Fetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html) for similar functionality.