# How to use facebook php sdk in google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use facebook php sdk in my app engine php application. But it gets an error.

when i use the statement `require 'facebook.php'` , it generates an error with the message-

> Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension

how do i get over with that exception?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Greg the error message says- "Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension"

Comment: To get rid of that error, you would have to enable the cURL extension – but apparently that’s not possible on GAE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571627/curl-on-app-engine

Comment: @CBroe okay i understand. So it would take good effort to convert the facebook php sdk files to use the urlfetch instead of cURL. Is there any easier way than that to use fb php sdk in app engine?

Comment: php on GAE is still experimental and curl is used by lots of applications. If the community wants it enough Google might add curl support

Comment: This patch to the facebook php SDK would fix it. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/pull/77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this branch of the SDK, that has http streams support.

https://github.com/camfitz/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. However, i have shifted my experiments to OpenShift, which seems very good so far, as a free service.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking to use the latest (version 4) Facebook SDK for PHP with Google App Engine, they can use this fork: https://github.com/ahsanity/facebook-php-sdk-v4-without-curl

The official SDK uses Curl to make all the API calls, making it unusable in environments that doesn't have the PHP Curl module enabled (example: Google App Engine)

This fork checks if PHP Curl module is enabled. If not, it falls back to using Http streams (via file_get_contents()). If Curl is detected, it uses Curl just like the official SDK.

Answer (score 0):

this library replaces curl with php http stream functions https://github.com/azayarni/purl

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, hence the previous answers. Anyone looking for an up-to-date solution can just download v5 or greater of the official Facebook PHP SDK. It natively supports various HTTP clients, Curl and HttpStreams included.

I just followed the installation instructions provided in their [PHP SDK Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) guide and it works on my GAE instance with no configuration or patching.